# overlay an image and show lighter pixel at each pixel location

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two black and white images that I would like to merge with the final image showing the lighter/ white pixel at each pixel location in both images. I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
background=Image.open('ABC.jpg').convert("RGBA")
overlay=Image.open('DEF.jpg').convert("RGBA")
background_width=1936
background_height=1863
background_width,background_height = background.size
overlay_resize= overlay.resize((background_width,background_height),Image.ANTIALIAS)
background.paste(overlay_resize, None, overlay_resize)
overlay=background.save("overlay.jpg")
fn=np.maximum(background,overlay)
fn1=PIL.Image.fromarray(fn)
plt.imshow(fnl)
plt.show()
```

The error message I get is cannot handle this data type. Any help or advice anyone could give would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things. You just need to read in both images and make them greyscale `numpy` arrays, then choose the lighter of the two pixels at each location.

So starting with these two images:

[image] [image]

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open two input images and convert to greyscale numpy arrays
bg=np.array(Image.open('a.png').convert('L'))
fg=np.array(Image.open('b.png').convert('L'))

# Choose lighter pixel at each location
result=np.maximum(bg,fg)

# Save
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

You will get this:

[image]

**Keywords:** numpy, Python, image, image processing, compose, blend, blend mode, lighten, lighter, Photoshop, equivalent, darken, overlay.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you were right my code was over complicating it. The above code works perfectly

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project!

Comment: When I try this code with a new image i get the error message "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1814,2085) (1863,1936). I was wondering how I would resolve this to make the shapes the same size so they can blend together? Thanks again for all the help so far

Comment: Oh, I didn't worry with the resizing because I thought you had that already worked out from your code. Do the `Image.open('a.png').convert('L')` part, then resize exactly how your were resizing before, then do the `np.array(resizedImage)` and carry on as I did.