# Creating a greyscale image with a Matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, jpeg, fft

I'm Marius, a maths student in the first year.

We have recieved a team-assignment where we have to implement a fourier transformation and we chose to try to encode the transformation of an image to a JPEG image.

to simplify the problem for ourselves, we chose to do it only for pictures that are greyscaled.
This is my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

#
#ALLEMAAL INFORMATIE GEEN BEREKENINGEN
img = Image.open('mario.png')  
img = img.convert('L') # convert to monochrome picture
img.show() #opens the picture
pixels = list(img.getdata())
print(pixels) #to see if we got the pixel numeric values correct
grootte = list(img.size)
print(len(pixels)) #to check if the amount of pixels is correct.
kolommen, rijen = img.size
print("het aantal kolommen is",kolommen,"het aantal rijen is",rijen)
#tot hier allemaal informatie

pixelMatrix = []
while pixels != []:
    pixelMatrix.append(pixels[:kolommen])
    pixels = pixels[kolommen:]
print(pixelMatrix)
pixelMatrix = np.array(pixelMatrix)
print(pixelMatrix.shape)
```

Now the problem forms itself in the last 3 lines. I want to try to convert the matrix of values back into an Image with the matrix 'pixelMatrix' as it's value.
I've tried many things, but this seems to be the most obvious way:

```
im2 = Image.new('L',(kolommen,rijen))
im2.putdata(pixels)
im2.show()
```

When I use this, it just gives me a black image of the correct dimensions.
Any ideas on how to get back the original picture, starting from the values in my matrix pixelMatrix?

Post Scriptum: We still have to implement the transformation itself, but that would be useless unless we are sure we can convert a matrix back into a greyscaled image.

Comment: Look here for example of converting image to Numpy array and then back to Pillow image... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399524/2836621

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, I need to transform monochrome values( that we have stored in a list/ matrix) into an image.

Comment: `PILimage = Image.fromarray(pixelMatrix)`